# Why is google geocode api sending curious results?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

When I enter this address '81 w Columbus Street, Lithopolis, OH 43136 into google maps it confirms the address, sends back the coordinates, and shows a marker on the map. However, when I use the same address in my script, I get an entirely different JSON address/response. 
Some code to work with if needed:

The Form:

```
 <form action="json-decode-script.php" name="my-form" id="my-form" method="post">

             <input name="street_add" id="street_add" type="textbox" placeholder="street addres" class="address">
             <input name="city" id="city" type="textbox" placeholder="city" class="address">
             <input name="state" id="state" type="textbox" placeholder="state" class="address">
             <input name="postcode" id="postcode" type="textbox" placeholder="zipcode" class="address">

             <input type="submit" id="submit" value="go">
           </form>
```

The Script:

```
<?php
$street_add = (isset($_POST['street_add'])) ? $_POST['street_add'] : '';
$city = (isset($_POST['city'])) ? $_POST['street_add'] : '';
$state = (isset($_POST['state'])) ? $_POST['street_add'] : '';
$postcode = (isset($_POST['postcode'])) ? $_POST['postcode'] : '';
$address = $street_add . ',' . $city . ',' . $state . ',' . $postcode;
$latitude = '';
$longitude = '';

    // Send Encoded address to google api
$json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.rawurlencode($address).'&sensor=false');
// Convert json to array
$array = json_decode($json);
// Results
$formatted =  $array->results[0]->formatted_address;
$latitude = $array->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitude = $array->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$theStreetNum = $array->results[0]->address_components[0]->long_name;
$theStreetName = $array->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name;
$street_add = $theStreetNum . ' ' . $theStreetName;
$theCity = $array->results[0]->address_components[3]->long_name;
$theState = $array->results[0]->address_components[6]->short_name;
$thePostCode = $array->results[0]->address_components[8]->long_name;

?><pre><?php
print_r($array);
?></pre>
```

Also note that other addresses I've used work as expected.

Comment: [the Google Maps Javascript API v3 geocoder seems to work for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=81%20w%20Columbus%20Street,%20Lithopolis,%20OH%2043136&geocode=1), looks like you are using the webservice.  What is the URL that you are using for your request.  What does the response look like?

Comment: The URL is in the code above ;) The result looks like a nicely formatted stdClass ;) (with the incorrect address). Also, the Javascript API works for me too! Which is why this is so strange! Some of the other responses I've seen suggest the different apis somehow work differently with results so.....

Comment: What is the final resulting URL of the code?

Comment: My [manual translation](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=81%20w%20Columbus%20Street,%20Lithopolis,%20OH%2043136&sensor=false) seems to work fine.

Comment: Although [you are not using the correct endpoint (per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests), it should be @ [maps.googleapis.com](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=81%20w%20Columbus%20Street,%20Lithopolis,%20OH%2043136&sensor=false) (though I doubt that will change anything)

Comment: The resulting URL was to my php script above. I didn't see anything in the developer tool indicating communication with the API, apart from the multidimensional-array returned as a result. I added the correct endpoint too-still the same incorrect result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41143/discussion-between-paul-yorde-and-geocodezip)